# Selling a portion of a co-op and taking full 250k deduction?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, primary-residence

I an single and own a 3-bedroom 2-floor co-op in NYC... the result of a combination of two units.

If I separate the duplex into two separate units and sell one (while keeping the other as my primary residence) can I take the full 250k deduction?

Lastly, if I live in the remaining unit for over two years and sell that down the road, can I take the same 250k deduction again for that property?